# problem with pick and place application tutorial

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, grasp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am following the tutorial in the  following link :
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Application

I am using ROS electric and the robot is a simulated one in Gazebo. I launch the pr2_table_top_manipulation.launch as outlined in the tutorial.

When I try to run the program for the first time an error message is displayed saying "Collision map processing service failed".

When I try to run the program next time following message is displayed:
"Waiting for collision processing service to come up"
"waitForService: Service [/tabletop_collision_map_processing/tabletop_collision_map_processing] could not connect to host [rufus-uav:56243], waiting..."

Can anybody suggest what might be going wrong?
Here is a link with the terminal outputs if anyone wants to have a look at it: http://prashanta-gyawali.blogspot.com/2012/07/picture-of-gazebo-with-pr2-and-terminal.html

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38601/problem-with-pick-and-place-application-tutorial/) by [Prashant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2710/prashant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like the collision map processing service crashed?  There's not nearly enough info to tell what happened.  Does this happen every time you run?  Simulated or real robot?  Electric or Fuerte?  Did you launch the robot and pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch first?

If you post a copy of the entire terminal output from where you launched pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch and also where you ran the tutorial program online someplace and put a link in your comment, I'll take a peek and give you my best guess about what's going wrong.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2012-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1